# Derivation of initial bearing calculation

Tags: bearing, geodesy

NOTE: I was recommended by another user that this would perhaps fit better in this stack, initial post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63354633/derivation-of-intial-bearing-calculation).

I needed to make calculations of the initial bearing between two coordinates described in latitude/longitude. I have found one formulation of this calculation as

[image]

Note, I tried formatting the equation with LaTeX but I couldn't see how to do that on stack, using $$ didn't seem to do anything.

This calculation can be found on various sites like link [1](https://www.igismap.com/formula-to-find-bearing-or-heading-angle-between-two-points-latitude-longitude/) [2](http://www.anycalculator.com/longitude.htm) [3](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) but I have not been able to find a derivation or a source for the calculation, as such I am looking for a derivation or an explanation of the derivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was surprised that I didn't find this ready-made question and answer on this site.

This formula is sometimes taken from http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html, which in turn is taken from http://www.edwilliams.org/avform.htm, but in neither of the two places is this derivation really explained.

Where it is done is in [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171219235009/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55417.html), which I limit myself to copying because it is self explanatory:

> Let's define three unit vectors, each in the direction of the line
> from the center of the earth to a point on the surface: N in the
> direction of the north pole, A in the direction of the initial point,
> and B in the direction of the final point on the course. Then the
> bearing we seek is the angle between the plane containing N and A,
> and the plane containing A and B. Thus it equals the angle between
> vectors perpendicular to these planes, namely, NxA and BxA.
>
> Let point A have latitude lat1 and longitude 0 (we can rotate our
> coordinate system so this is true), and let point B have latitude
> lat2 and longitude dlon (the difference between the actual longitudes
> of A and B). Then we can calculate NxA and BxA:
>
> ```
>  N = (0, 0, 1)
>  A = (cos(lat1), 0, sin(lat1))
>  B = (cos(lat2)*cos(dlon), cos(lat2)*sin(dlon), sin(lat2))
>
>  NxA = (0, cos(lat1), 0)
>  BxA = (sin(lat1)*cos(lat2)*sin(dlon),
>         cos(lat1)*sin(lat2)-sin(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(dlon),
>         -cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*sin(dlon))
> ```
>
> The usual way to find the angle would be to take the dot product of
> these vectors, divide by the product of the magnitudes of the vectors,
> and take the arccosine. But that would be quite a mess. Instead we
> can take advantage of the fact that NxA is parallel to the y axis.
> The tangent of the angle between BxA and the y axis is the component
> of BxA in the x-z plane (the square root of the sum of the squares of
> the x and z components) divided by the y component:
>
> ```
>  tan(theta) = sqrt((sin(lat1)*cos(lat2)*sin(dlon))^2 + 
>                    (-cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*sin(dlon))^2) / 
>               (cos(lat1)*sin(lat2)-sin(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(dlon))
> ```
>
> The numerator simplifies to
>
> ```
>  = cos(lat2)*sin(dlon)
> ```
>
> Thus
>
> ```
>  tan(theta) = cos(lat2)*sin(dlon) / 
>               (cos(lat1)*sin(lat2)-sin(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(dlon))
> ```
>
> That's the formula. If we take the arctan of both sides, we get a
> value in the range from -pi/2 to pi/2 radians. The problem is, this
> doesn't distinguish between opposite directions, NE vs. SW for
> instance. But the function atan2(y,x) returns the arctan of y/x with
> adjustments for the signs of x and y so that the angle returned is
> the angle of the cartesian point (x,y) in polar coordinates -- just
> what we need here.
>
> The only problem is that it returns a value in the range (-pi, pi].
> The function mod(..., 2*pi) moves negative angles up to the range
> (pi, 2*pi). To get a final answer in degrees (0 to 360), you must
> multiply by 180/pi.

Comment: I was surprised as well that it wasn't already addressed, but thank you.